# How to loop an array of packages in an Ansible role

Tags: arrays, loops, ansible, roles

I have made role for installing php5-fpm (with other roles: nginx, worldpress, mysql). I want to install php5 set of packages, but have problem with the looping an array of packages. Please some tips how to solve this issue.

Role php5-fpm include:

- roles/default/main.yml
- roles/tasks/install.yml

default/main.yml:

```
---
# defaults file for php-fpm
# filename: roles/php5-fpm/defaults/main.yml
#
php5:
  packages:
    - php5-fpm
    - php5-common
    - php5-curl
    - php5-mysql
    - php5-cli
    - php5-gd
    - php5-mcrypt
    - php5-suhosin
    - php5-memcache
  service:
    name: php5-fpm
```

tasks/install.yml:

```
# filename: roles/php5-fpm/tasks/install.yml
#
- name: install php5-fpm and family
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: php5.packages
  notify:
    - restart php5-fpm service
```

I want that "with_items" from install.yml look into defaults/main.yml and take that array of packages

Answer (score 0):

Expand the variable

wrong

```
with_items: php5.packages
```

correct

```
loop: "{{ php5.packages }}"
```

---

Quoting from [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

> - We added **loop** in Ansible 2.5. It is not yet a full replacement for with_, but we **recommend** it for most use cases.
> - We have not deprecated the use of with_ - that syntax will still be valid for the foreseeable future.
> - We are looking to improve loop syntax - watch this page and the changelog for updates.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for the fast reaction. It's work fine with the loops.